# how to alter table to add two or more foreign keys

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I tried using the code below to add two foreign keys to the table products but it wont add foreign keys if i run the two on one run, they work individualy but not if i code it the way below:

```
 ALTER TABLE products
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (CategoryI)  REFERENCES categories (CategoryID),
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (SupplierID) REFERENCES suppliers (SupplierID);
```

two alter table to make two foreign keys from separate tables

Comment: What is the error you get? The code [works just fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/kkzhV_Lb) Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That has been [discontinued](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for 6 years now. You should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.